# how map certain USDA hardiness zones in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

Has anyone been able to create maps of a selection of USDA hardiness zones in R, maybe with [ggplot2 and sf packages](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf.html)? I'd specifically like to create a map with only zones 9b and higher in color [image: USDA hardiness zones].

I think some of the data to create the map is found here [Prism Climate Group](http://prism.oregonstate.edu/projects/plant_hardiness_zones.php), but I am inexperienced and at a loss to know what to do with GIS data (file extensions SGML,XML,DBF, PRJ, SHP,SHX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate a little bit on the answer by @niloc:

The USA looks more natural when shown in the Albers conical projection (Canada border slightly curved - like in the original image).

This can be achieved by using `coord_sf(crs = 5070)` in your {ggplot2} call.

The gist of the answer (downloading, unzipping & plotting via `ggplot2::geom_sf()`) remains unchanged).

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(USAboundaries)

# Download and unzip file
temp_shapefile <- tempfile()
download.file('http://prism.oregonstate.edu/projects/public/phm/phm_us_shp.zip', temp_shapefile)
unzip(temp_shapefile)

# Read full shapefile
shp_hardness <- read_sf('phm_us_shp.shp')

# Subset to zones 9b and higher
shp_hardness_subset <- shp_hardness %>%
  filter(str_detect(ZONE, '9b|10a|10b|11a|11b'))

# state boundaries for context
usa <- us_boundaries(type="state", resolution = "low") %>% 
  filter(!state_abbr %in% c("PR", "AK", "HI"))  # lower 48 only

# Plot it
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = shp_hardness_subset, aes(fill = ZONE)) +
  geom_sf(data = usa, color = 'black', fill = NA) +
  coord_sf(crs = 5070) +
  theme_void() # remove lat/long grid lines
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Also seems cleaner to not have to mix `geom_polygon` and `geom_sf` unnecessarily.

Comment: @nniloc thanks! The world has moved a bit since {maps} was a news, and the  {sf} package format seems to be the next big thing in spatial applications - but the principle of your answer stands fiirm

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot going on in that map with all of the insets, the legend with F and C, states displayed over the CONUS. Would be better to narrow down your question.

But here is a start. The shapefile is composed of many files (XML, DBF, etc) but you only need to point `read_sf()` at the `.shp` file. Subsetting with an `sf` object can be done just like with a `data.frame`.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# Download and unzip file
temp_shapefile <- tempfile()
download.file('http://prism.oregonstate.edu/projects/public/phm/phm_us_shp.zip', temp_shapefile)
unzip(temp_shapefile)

# Read full shapefile
shp_hardness <- read_sf('phm_us_shp.shp')

# Subset to zones 9b and higher
shp_hardness_subset <- shp_hardness %>%
  filter(str_detect(ZONE, '9b|10a|10b|11a|11b'))


# Plot it
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = shp_hardness_subset, aes(fill = ZONE)) +
  geom_polygon(data = map_data("state"), # add states for context
               aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group), 
               color = 'black', 
               fill = NA) +
  theme_void() # remove lat/long grid lines
```

[image]